# Recursively ftp download, then extract gz files

Tags: r

I have a multiple-step file download process I would like to do within R. I have got the middle step, but not the first and third...

```
# STEP 1 Recursively find all the files at an ftp site 
# ftp://prism.oregonstate.edu//pub/prism/pacisl/grids
all_paths <- #### a recursive listing of the ftp path contents??? ####

# STEP 2 Choose all the ones whose filename starts with "hi"
all_files <- sapply(sapply(strsplit(all_paths, "/"), rev), "[", 1)
hawaii_log <- substr(all_files, 1, 2) == "hi"
hi_paths <- all_paths[hawaii_log]
hi_files <- all_files[hawaii_log]

# STEP 3 Download & extract from gz format into a single directory
mapply(download.file, url = hi_paths, destfile = hi_files)
## and now how to extract from gz format?
```

Comment: Must it be R? It's passable at best with HTTP, but it's not exactly great at FTP. A more general purpose language, like python, would be much better suited to this sort of problem.

Comment: yeah, I am trying to avoid adding any outside tools... for now I already did a workaround by calling command line wget from R, but I'd like to be able to pass this on to somebody as a self-contained R script

Comment: It's easy enough to just copy and paste the text file names and use download.file in a loop - so it's hardcoded for your user, but still self-contained (or you could ftp into the site and mget . . .)

Comment: You could use `dir(pattern = "^hi.+$", ignore.case = TRUE)` to get all "hi" files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can read the contents of the ftp page if I start R with the `internet2` option. I.e.

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12\bin\x64\Rgui.exe --internet2
```

(The shortcut to start R on Windows can be modified to add the internet2 argument - right-click /Properties /Target, or just run that at the command line - and obvious on GNU/Linux).

The text on that page can be read like this:

```
 download.file("ftp://prism.oregonstate.edu//pub/prism/pacisl/grids", "f.txt")
 txt <- readLines("f.txt")
```

It's a little more work to parse out the Directory listings, then read them recursively for the underlying files.

```
## (something like)
dirlines <- txt[grep("Directory <A HREF=", txt)]

## split and extract text after "grids/"
split1 <- sapply(strsplit(dirlines, "grids/"), function(x) rev(x)[1])

## split and extract remaining text after "/"
sapply(strsplit(split1, "/"), function(x) x[1])
[1] "dem"    "ppt"    "tdmean" "tmax"   "tmin"
```

It's about here that this stops seeming very attractive, and gets a bit laborious so I would actually recommend a different option. There would no doubt be a better solution perhaps with RCurl, and I would recommend learning to use and ftp client for you and your user. Command line ftp, anonymous logins, and mget all works pretty easily.

The internet2 option was explained for a similar ftp site here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-January/184647.html

Comment: The first part is handy to know. Instead of the startup option there is also `setInternet2(TRUE)`. I suppose a recursive function for the subdirectories is a way to do it from there but at least now I can get the text from the page.

Answer (score 7):

For part 1, RCurl might be helpful. The `getURL` function retrieves one or more URLs;  `dirlistonly` lists the contents of the directory without retrieving the file. The rest of the function creates the next level of url

```
library(RCurl)
getContent <- function(dirs) {
    urls <- paste(dirs, "/", sep="")
    fls <- strsplit(getURL(urls, dirlistonly=TRUE), "\r?\n")
    ok <- sapply(fls, length) > 0
    unlist(mapply(paste, urls[ok], fls[ok], sep="", SIMPLIFY=FALSE),
           use.names=FALSE)
}
```

So starting with

```
dirs <- "ftp://prism.oregonstate.edu//pub/prism/pacisl/grids"
```

we can invoke this function and look for things that look like directories, continuing until done

```
fls <- character()
while (length(dirs)) {
    message(length(dirs))
    urls <- getContent(dirs)
    isgz <- grepl("gz$", urls)
    fls <- append(fls, urls[isgz])
    dirs <- urls[!isgz]
}
```

we could then use `getURL` again, but this time on `fls` (or elements of `fls`, in a loop) to retrieve the actual files. Or maybe better open a url connection and use gzcon to decompress and process on the file. Along the lines of

```
con <- gzcon(url(fls[1], "r"))
meta <- readLines(con, 7)
data <- scan(con, integer())
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me: I get a `1` `5` then `Error in dots[[1L]][[1L]] : subscript out of bounds` I tried to step thru: the first `fls` assignment tacks a `\r` on the end of the urls which doesnt seem to be a valid directory. Interesting that `dirlistonly` doesn't show up in the `getURL()` help page.

Comment: I guess on Windows the strsplit should be "\r\n*". RCurl depends on a system library, and specific options available depend on the version of the library installed. see `listCurlOptions()`; on Linux / MacOS one could use `man curl_easy_setopt`; not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 3):

```
ftp.root <- where are the files
dropbox.root <- where to put the files

#=====================================================================
#   Function that downloads files from URL
#=====================================================================

fdownload <- function(sourcelink) { 

  targetlink <- paste(dropbox.root, substr(sourcelink, nchar(ftp.root)+1, 
nchar(sourcelink)), sep = '')

  # list of contents
  filenames <- getURL(sourcelink, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
  filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\n")
  filenames <- unlist(filenames)

  files <- filenames[grep('\\.', filenames)]  
  dirs <- setdiff(filenames, files)
  if (length(dirs) != 0) {
    dirs <- paste(sourcelink, dirs, '/', sep = '')
  }  

  # files
  for (filename in files) {

    sourcefile <- paste(sourcelink, filename, sep = '')
    targetfile <- paste(targetlink, filename, sep = '')

    download.file(sourcefile, targetfile)
  }

  # subfolders
  for (dirname in dirs) {

    fdownload(dirname)
  }
}
```

Comment: to call the function:  fdownload(ftp.root)