# Retrieve the list of files from a URL

Tags: r

I would like to get a list of all the files available at this address: http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/
(publicly available data from the NOAA).

It would be some sort of "list.files" for the a specific URL.
I started to take a look at RCurl but all I could get was the HTML code of the URL.

Comment: all I get are plain text files, all data. how did you get the HTML code?

Comment: I used this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227444/recursively-ftp-download-then-extract-gz-files) as a basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can simply use `readHTMLTable`:

```
readHTMLTable("http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/", 
              skip.rows=1:2)[[1]]$Name -> file.list
```

Then to create a list of paths:

```
paste("http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cmb/drought/weekly-palmers/2005/", 
      file.list[!is.na(file.list)], sep="") -> path.list
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work here: `https://vip.arizona.edu/vipdata/V4/DATAPOOL/PHENOLOGY/`. Calling:
`readHTMLTable("https://vip.arizona.edu/vipdata/V4/DATAPOOL/PHENOLOGY/", 
              skip.rows=1:2)[[1]]$Name -> file.list` 
returns: 
`Error in XML::readHTMLTable("https://vip.arizona.edu/vipdata/V4/DATAPOOL/PHENOLOGY/",  : 
  subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://vip.arizona.edu/vipdata/V4/DATAPOOL/PHENOLOGY/' `