# Fetching links to PDF files from an HTML file in R

Tags: r

I am currently attempting to write a program in R, which can download the PDF files uploaded to the website https://www.emmi-benchmarks.eu/euribor-org/euribor-intraday-re-fixing.html

If we click into the website right now, we can see 3 pdf files at the bottom of the page. I'd like my program to be able to download these 3 files without any manual work. Would this be possible?

I'm able to download the PDF files one by one and fetch the wanted information when I have the link to the respective file - but the name of these files may be updated and new ones may be added, so manually entering the links is not a long term solution if it can be avoided.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15954463/680068 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/12930933/680068

Comment: Try the solutions from the links, let us know if they do not work.