# Importing a csv.gz file from an FTP server with Port and Directory Credentials into R

Tags: r, csv, ftp, rcurl

I want to import datasets in R that come from an FTP server. I am using FileZilla to manually see the files. Currently my data is in a xxxx.csv.gz file in the FTP server and a new file gets added once a day.

My issues are that I have tried using the following link as guidance and it doesn't seem to work well in my case:
[Using R to download newest files from ftp-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235421/using-r-to-download-newest-files-from-ftp-server)

When I attempt the following code an error message comes up:

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "ftp://yourServer"
userpwd <- "yourUser:yourPass"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd,
         ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,dirlistonly = TRUE)
```

Error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to ftp.xxxx.com port 21: Timed out
```

The reason why this happened is because under the credentials: it states that I should use Port: 22 for secure port

How do I modify my getURL function so that I can access Port: 22?

Also there is a directory after making this call that I need to get to in order to access the files.

For example purposes: let's say the directory is:

Directory: /xxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx

(I've also tried attaching this to the original URL callout and the same error message comes up)

Basically I want to get access to this directory, upload individual csv.gz files into R and then automatically call the following day's data.

The file names are:
XXXXXX_20160205.csv.gz

(The file names are just dates and each file will correspond to the previous day)

I guess the first step is to just make a connection to the files and download them and later down the road, automatically call the previous day's csv.gz file.

Any help would be great, thanks!