# How to download latest file from FTP when the name of the files do not contain the date

Tags: r, ftp

Using R, I need to download the latest file from   ***ftp.nhc.noaa.gov/atcf/fst*** I need to download the most recent file uploaded.

I don't want to download the entire list of file and check the dates and the files do not contain the date in their names.

These are the list of files. Need some guidance on how to do with R.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What file from what website? Could you start with today's date and move backwards until you hit a file?

Comment: the website is: ftp://ftp.nhc.noaa.gov/atcf/fst/
I need to download the most recent file uploaded

Comment: Give all the details in first place to improve chances of getting answers. : Review

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using R to download newest files from ftp-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235421/using-r-to-download-newest-files-from-ftp-server)

Comment: Same question i also had. Download latest file from ftp site based on the `last modified time`. The possible duplicate above downloads all the files and uses file name