# How to push .csv file through FTP using R?

Tags: r, ftp

I am trying to send data to a certain server using R Programming but unable to send.

Not sure what I am doing wrong? It is with reading the file or attempt to push the file? I have tried using filezilla and was able to transfer the data.

```
ftpUpload(read.csv(file = 'input/Anone_20190131185020.csv', header = TRUE),
          ("ftp://103.X.X.X/ABCDHOSOLAR/"),
          userpwd = "XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX"
      )
```

Error in file(what, "rb") : invalid 'description' argument

Comment: take a look at [this](http://felixfan.github.io/download-files/) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235421/using-r-to-download-newest-files-from-ftp-server/22237993) post

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. The link above is about accessing a file in the server (if I am not wrong) what I am looking for is to send data to the server using FTP push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the `read.csv()` function.

```
ftpUpload('input/Anone_20190131185020.csv',
          "ftp://103.X.X.X/ABCDHOSOLAR/",
          userpwd = "login:password"      )
```

Comment: Thank you for that correction. But I am still getting the below error

`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Uploading to a URL without a file name!`

Comment: What is your OS (mac/linux/windows) ? The issue seems to be on the file path. Maybe you should use the full path of the file to upload. `library(RCurl)
ftpUpload("---full_path---/Localfile.csv", "ftp://User:Password@FTPServer/Destination.csv")`

Comment: I am using windows OS. Thanks, it is working but it is overwriting an existing file (as we are mentioning the file name, I guess) with the file I am pushing through FTP.

Can you help me determine a way to push the file itself and not overwriting any?

Comment: You can add a timestamp :
`filename <- paste0("---full_path---/Localfile",gsub(pattern = "-|:| ",x=as.character(Sys.time()),replacement = ""),".csv")`

Comment: It is working now :)

Thank you for your help on this!!